# Angular Test Error - NullInjectorError: No provider for TrimInputDirective

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, angular-directive, angular-unit-test

I created an Angular Directive, that uses CSS selectors to automatically trim inputs in my application, it looks like so...

```
import { Directive, HostListener, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

export const TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrimInputDirective),
  multi: true
};

/**
 * The trim accessor for writing trimmed value and listening to changes that is
 * used by the {@link NgModel}, {@link FormControlDirective}, and
 * {@link FormControlName} directives.
 */
/* tslint:disable */
@Directive({
  selector: `
    input
    :not([type=checkbox])
    :not([type=radio])
    :not([type=password])
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [formControlName],

    input
    :not([type=checkbox])
    :not([type=radio])
    :not([type=password])
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [formControl],

    input
    :not([type=checkbox])
    :not([type=radio])
    :not([type=password])
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [ngModel],

    textarea
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [formControlName],

    textarea
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [formControl],

    textarea
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)[ngModel],
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [ngDefaultControl]'
  `,
  providers: [ TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
/* tslint:enable */
export class TrimInputDirective extends DefaultValueAccessor {

  protected _onTouched: any;

  /**
   * ngOnChange - Lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes.
   * @param {string} val - trim value onChange.
   */
  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  public ngOnChange = (val: string) => {
    this.onChange(val.trim());
  }

  /**
   * applyTrim - trims the passed value
   * @param {string} val - passed value.
   */
  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
  public applyTrim(val: string) {
    this.writeValue(val.trim());
    this._onTouched();
  }

  /**
   * writeValue - trims the passed value
   * @param {any} value - passed  value.
   */
  public writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      value = value.trim();
    }

    super.writeValue(value);
  }

  /**
   * registerOnTouched Registers a callback function that should be called when the control receives a blur event.
   * @param {function} fn - The user information.
   */
  public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this._onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

Now being a good developer I must right some unit tests... so I start to put a file together, here it is

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {TrimInputDirective} from './trim-input.directive';

import {expect} from 'chai';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-directive-test-component',
  template: ''
})
class TestComponent {
}

describe('Trim Directive', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let inputDebugElement: any;
  let directive: TrimInputDirective;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        TrimInputDirective
      ],
      providers: []
    }).overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
      set: {
        template: '<input type="text">'
      }
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      inputDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
      directive = inputDebugElement.injector.get(TrimInputDirective);
    });
  }));

  it('should trim the input', () => {
    directive.ngOnChange('     1234.56     ')
    expect('1234.56').to.be('1234.56'); // I know this isn't the correct test... I will amend this
  });
});
```

Now I wish to run my tests just to make sure that the setup in the spec file is correct, but I get the following error:

> HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) Trim Directive "before each"
>   hook for "should trim the input" FAILED   Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[TrimInputDirective]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TrimInputDirective]: 
>         NullInjectorError: No provider for TrimInputDirective!  Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[TrimInputDirective]:

I don't understand why I get this error, why do I have to provide the directive? I don't think this is necessary, also if I must provide what do I provide? Providing the actual directive doesn't work / resolve the error? I am very confused. If anyone can tell me how to resolve the issue or why I get it I would be most appreciative.

Please note that this is a legacy Angular App and was built before the
AngularCLI was available. So it is a little unorthodox (for example it isn't using Jasmin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You don't need to provide your directive, you just need to declare it in the `TestingModule`. Then, it will be used in the template with the corresponding selectors.

2) Your selector does not correspond to the one used on your input. Remove `formControlName` if you want it to apply to all inputs of certain types or change your test.

```
input
    :not([type=checkbox])
    :not([type=radio])
    :not([type=password])
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
    [formControlName],
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

3) The Directive gets triggered on certain events. You need to simulate those events to see an effect. Have a look at this simplified example. ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-bshvw1?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts))

```
@Directive({
  selector: `
    input
    :not([type=checkbox])
    :not([type=radio])
    :not([type=password])
    :not([readonly])
    :not(.ng-trim-ignore)
  `
})
export class TrimInputDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('blur') onLeave() {
   if (this.el.nativeElement.value)
    this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.trim();
  }

}
```

And the test:

```
describe('Trim Directive', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let inputDebugElement: any;
  let directive: TrimInputDirective;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        TrimInputDirective
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule],
      providers: []
    }).overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
      set: {
        template: '<input type="text">'
      }
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
      inputDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }); 
  }));

  it('should trim the input', () => {
    inputDebugElement.value = '     1234.56     ';
    inputDebugElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputDebugElement.value).toBe('1234.56'); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide directive in your `TestComponent` something like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-directive-test-component',
  template: '',
  providers: [ TrimInputDirective ]
})
class TestComponent {
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I was then asked for further providers, naturally that was the first thing I tried. Something is wrong with my implementation I think

Comment: Directives should be declared not provided. https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#build-a-simple-attribute-directive